# How to get the content between the brackets of String arrays passed as arguments to a Scala main method?

Tags: scala, parsing, command-line, pattern-matching

I have made a program that prints the sum of two arrays received as command line arguments:

```
object MyPackage{
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println(sumTwoLists(stringToIntList(args(0)), stringToIntList(args(1))))
  }

  private def sumTwoLists(list_1 : List[Int], list_2 : List[Int]) : List[Int] = {
    (list_1, list_2).zipped.map(_ + _)
  }

  private def stringToIntList(string: String) : List[Int] = {
    string.split(",").map(s => s.toInt).toList
  }
}
```

`sbt "run 1,2,3 4,5,6"` works fine:

```
List(5, 7, 9)
```

My question is, how can I make it work for `sbt "run [1,2,3] [4,5,6]"`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to transform the string "[1,2,3]" to list List(1,2,3) :

```
private def stringToIntList(string: String) : List[Int] = {
    string.drop(1).dropRight(1).split(",").map(s => s.toInt).toList
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Thomas is correct.

If you however also wanted to ensure the syntax was correct you could use a regex with a group:

```
object Parser{
  lazy val r = new Regex("\\[(\\d(,\\d)?)\\]","numbers")
  def stringToIntList(t : String): Option[List[Int]] =
    r.findFirstMatchIn(t).map(m=>m.group("numbers").split(",").map(_.toInt).toList)
}

Parser.stringToIntList("[1]") //Some(List(1))
Parser.stringToIntList("[1,2]") //Some(List(1, 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

I want to share more generic solution than this proposed by Thomas:

```
  def stringToIntList(string: String) : List[Int] = {
    string.filter(o => o.isDigit || o.equals(',')).split(',').map(o => o.toInt).toList
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use https://github.com/scopt/scopt which is advanced command line parsing library

Answer (score 0):

The input parameter will be two strings `"[1,2,3]"` and `"[4,5,6]"`. You need to parse them into `List` type first.